# Shift letters from input to the next in alpabhet

Tags: javascript

I have been searching the web and I have found a few examples about my current problem, and all seems to be addressing the same topic: deciphering text. But I cannot find anything written in javascript. I gave it a shot, but I'm stuck when trying to convert the string in to an array.

Lets say that the current alphabet is

```
var alpabhet=[
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','å','ä','ö'
];
```

And I have a string `ammj`, that I enter in the input. Then I want to be able to shift with right and left key and view the output of that current shift. So a shift of two (2) would result in the string `cool`. And a shift of 5 for the string `åjjg` would also result in `cool`.

So my main concern is, how can I convert a user input to an array with javascript?

I have a input filed:`<input id="text_to_be_shifted" type="text">` and then I'm trying to loop the input and arrange into a array

```
var values = {};
var inputs = document.getElementById('text_to_be_shifted');
for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    values[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
}
```

Have a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8kqmdL1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a live and working example, with a check so that shifting letter 'a' with -1 will convert it to last letter of the alphabet 'ö', -2 to   'ä' e.t.c. and shifting last letter of alphabet with 1 will set it to 'a', with 2 to 'b' e.t.c:

```js
  var alpabhet=[
'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','å','ä','ö'
];

var values = {};
var inputs = document.getElementById('text_to_be_shifted');
for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
 values[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
}
function outputText(number){
   var newtext = [];
  var inputtext = document.getElementById('text_to_be_shifted').value.split('');
   inputtext.forEach(letter=> {
   var ind_ofLetter = alpabhet.indexOf(letter);
  ind_ofLetter = ind_ofLetter + number;
  if (ind_ofLetter < 0){
     ind_ofLetter = alpabhet.length + ind_ofLetter;
  }else if(ind_ofLetter > alpabhet.length-1){
     ind_ofLetter = ind_ofLetter -  alpabhet.length;
  }
  newtext.push(alpabhet[ind_ofLetter]);
   });
   document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].innerHTML = newtext.join('');
}

function shiftUp() {
 var currentShift = document.getElementById('currentShift');
 var number = currentShift.innerHTML;
 number++;
 currentShift.innerHTML = number;
  outputText(number);
}

function shiftDown() {
 var currentShift = document.getElementById('currentShift');
 var number = currentShift.innerHTML;
 number--;
 currentShift.innerHTML = number;
  outputText(number);
}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

 e = e || window.event;

 if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    console.log('left arrow')
    shiftDown()
 }
 else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
  console.log('right arrow')
  shiftUp()
 }

}
```

```html
<b>Current shift: </b><span id="currentShift">0</span>

<br><input id="text_to_be_shifted" type="text">
<div id='output' class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one input, so there is no point in looping over it.

To get an array, you should use something like:

```
document.getElementById('text_to_be_shifted').split("");
```

You can then use the map function to shift the elements

```
let arr = document.getElementById('text_to_be_shifted').split("");

let shifted = arr.map((c) => alpabhet[(alpabhet.indexOf(c) + 1) % alpabhet.length]).join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop you can utilize the charAt() function to get the individual character at a given index. W3 schools has a good lesson on this function if needed: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp

```
var inputArray = [];
var inputs = document.getElemenById('text_to_be_shifted');
for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
     inputArray[i] = inputs.charAt(i);
}
```

Something like this should work to get you an array with a single letter at each index.